# Need MemoryStream c# in IOS

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, stream, binary

I need to find the equivalence of the following code for IOS.

```
byte[] encodedMess;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
       writer.Write(message.getType().ToString();
       writer.Write(message.toJSONString());
    }
    encodedMess = stream.ToArray();
  }
```

I have already tried some tricks and find shorts code on internet, but nothing works :(

You are my last chance... I must have a byte array like encodedMess..

Thanks to every help (Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: What do you mean in iOS? You need this translated to objective c?

Comment: We are not going to write this for you. Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I need to put some class's informations in a byte array, but i'm a beginner in Obj C and I don't find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Coca Streams:

```
NSOutputStream *memoryStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToMemory];
[memoryStream open];
[memoryStream write:(uint8_t*)"Hello World" maxLength:11];
[memoryStream close];

NSData *data = [memoryStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];

void *buffer = calloc(12, 1);
NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:data];
[inputStream open];
[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:11];
[inputStream close];

NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The API that you are looking for is called `NSCoder`. You will find hundreds of questions and examples here in stackoverflow on how to use it.

Comment: Ok thx. The NSCoder variable will be used as the stream or the binary Writer ? I need to respect exactly the c# format of encodedMess

Comment: If you have to respect the binary format of other platforms `NSCoder` will not work as it has its own format. You can use `NSOutputStream` but you will have to create the binary representation of your data yourself. (How is the length of the string is stored? Which byte order do you have to use? etc)

Comment: :O That's what I expected.. It's a hard work to get the same binary representation..

Comment: I read that i can't transform strings to binary. Is it right ? Because I need to convert int, string, bool

Comment: Do you have any example with NSOutputStream ? I'm trying to find a solution, but i don't :(

Comment: 1) You can transform strings to binary but it will use some proprietary format of iOS. 2) you can find hundreds of examples here in stackoverflow, with google and even in apple's official doc http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html